# Advice: PHP HTML questionnaire form with pagination

Tags: php, html, forms, pagination

I have been tasked with creating a (quite long) questionnaire form, and save the responses to an SQL database. I'd like to split it up into easier to digest chunks - my idea was to use pagination. E.g. 1 page for personal details, a second page for feedback on topic #1, a 3rd page for feedback on topic #2 etc.

I have used pagination to read from databases with filters. I have used forms to write to databases; but I am having trouble trying to conceptualise how I might paginate an html form, and submit ($_POST) data only after the entire form has been completed (I can see that navigating to a different page will lose any form info). The questionnaire size will be dynamic over time as new questions get added, and old ones deleted.

My thoughts so far: 
a) Write to the database after completing each page, and if the user wants to return to that page, reading the info back in, pre-filling the fields, allowing them to edit...
b) using $_SESSION variables to store each field of a page once the NEXT button is pressed, and only $_POSTing at the very end of the form, recalling all session variables. Though how I might structure this final $_POST statement I am not sure, I have never used session variables in a $_POST statement.

I am inclined to use only HTML, CSS and PHP - mainly because I have very little experience with JavaScript, AJAX etc.

Does anyone have any experience creating such a paginated form using HTML and PHP only? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'd store everything in DB after each step. If a user decides halfway through they dont want to finish and exits at least you'd have that data. With the sessions that data will be gone (or a pain for you to find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be a lot easier if you add jquery in it, since that you are not familiar with jquery..here's the quick code for you:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="first">
        personal details
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="second" style="display:none">
        feedback on topic #1
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="third" style="display:none">
        feedback on topic #2
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<br><br>
<div id="page_menus">
    <a id="get_first" style="cursor:pointer">1</a>
    <a id="get_second" style="cursor:pointer">2</a>
    <a id="get_third" style="cursor:pointer">3</a>
</div>

<script>
    $('#get_first').click(function(){
        $('#first').show()
        $('#second').hide()
        $('#third').hide()
    })
    $('#get_second').click(function(){
        $('#first').hide()
        $('#second').show()
        $('#third').hide()
    })
    $('#get_third').click(function(){
        $('#first').hide()
        $('#second').hide()
        $('#third').show()
    })
</script>
```

it first hides the second and third divs, revealing it using jquery when the page number is clicked. it is quite simple so just modify the code

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k66fr816/)

Comment: Cool, thank you. Would this still work with PHP code embedded in between the <DIV> tags (I use PHP in there to filter questions etc)? I will try this out tomorrow, it is the end of my working day now :)

Comment: this would works as long as you wont alter the div ids and the jquery code, you can freely replace the content inside each divs

Comment: Thank you Kelvin. I will give feedback as soon as I have had a chance to try.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, I have become a little stuck, only the first 'oage' shows, and I get no menu buttons to navigate to the next 'page':

Comment: Hi Kelvin, Sorry about the previous comment... I have become a little stuck, it seems that the following does not work, can you suggest an improvement...? 'code' <?php
            foreach ($ListSections as $ShowHide)
   {
    $MyPage = "Page" . $PageID;
    $MyGet = "get_" . $PageID;
    
    ?>
            
    
     var my_page = <?php echo json_encode($MyPage); echo ("\n");?>
     var my_get = <?php echo json_encode($MyGet); echo ("\n");?>

     $('#my_get').click(function(){
     $('#my_page').show();} I am not sure what fiddle is?

Comment: i don't understand, can you show me how you used my code?

Comment: I now have it working, thank you, my solution was:   var my_get = <?php echo json_encode("#" . $MyGet); echo ("\n");?>;

     $(my_get).click(function()